# Spring Integration SFTP inbound adapter unable to copy files

Tags: file, sftp, spring-integration, jsch, inbound

I have a SFTP inbound channel set up to poll a remote sftp server and copy files to a local directory. When it runs, it gives me a 'Permission denied' error, but in the log file it correctly mentions the file name. So it appears to be able to correctly list the contents of the remote path, but is unable to read the files.

I haven't been able to figure out what the access issue is exactly. When i fiddled with it on a test server i could see I would get the same issue if the sftp user had at least r-x access on the remote dir, but no access on the files themselves. However on the live server where i get the issue, the user does have this required level of access.

Running the sftp command copies the files without any issues:

```
/usr/bin/sftp -2 -i KEYFILE USER@SERVER:REMOTEDIR/FILEPATTERN* LOCALDIR
```

Here is how i have the SFTP channel in my Spring Integration config:

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="${fixed.rate}" />

<bean id="sftpClientFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${sftp.inbound.channel.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${sftp.inbound.channel.availableServerPort}" />
    <property name="user" value="${sftp.inbound.channel.userid}" />
    <property name="password" value="${sftp.inbound.channel.password}" />
    <property name="privateKey" value="file:///${sftp.inbound.channel.server.key}"></property>
</bean>

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbound"
    channel="sftpChannel" session-factory="sftpClientFactory"
    filename-pattern="${input.file.format}" auto-create-local-directory="true"
    delete-remote-files="false" remote-directory="${sftp.inbound.channel.remote.directory}"
    local-directory="${sftp.inbound.channel.local.directory}">
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="sftpChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
```

The project is using Spring Integration version 4.0.4-RELEASE

This is the full exception trace. The file name gets correctly logged at the placeholder <FILENAME>

> ERROR 9860 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory
>       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:167)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
>       at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory
>       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyFileToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:238)
>       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:177)
>       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
>       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
>       ... 20 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to read file <FILENAME>; nested exception is 3: Permission denied
>       at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.read(SftpSession.java:132)
>       at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyFileToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:231)
>       ... 24 more
>   Caused by: 3: Permission denied
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1313)
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1266)
>       at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.read(SftpSession.java:128)
>       ... 25 more

I'll appreciate if anyone can help me figure out what I may be missing.

Comment: Did you actually try to `get` a file from the command line or just open the connection? Nothing jumps out to me; try turning on [jsch debug logging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-jsch-logging) to see if it gives you any hints.

Comment: yes, i was previously using this command to copy the files from the remote server into a local dir (LOCALDIR):

`/usr/bin/sftp -2 -i KEYFILE USER@SERVER:REMOTEDIR/FILEPATTERN* LOCALDIR`

and it still worked, so i can get the file from the command line. but with spring integration the odd thing was that i couldn't copy the file, even though the file name appears correctly in the log file.
the -2 switch specifies the use protocol version 2, but i couldn't find how to specify that in spring integration. i'll check with debug logging and get back.